# How can I initialize struct with values from array of interface in Go?

Tags: go

I'm getting a message from server like [0,"on",[6,1,5,"market",45.7]] and save it to []interface{} variable. I want to initialize struct with values of this array.
I'm totally new in Go and try to do it like:

```
import "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
...
var msg []interface{}
// Server send response: `[0,"on",[6,1,5,"market",45.7]]`
if err := websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &msg); err != nil {
    logger.Println(err)
} else {
    type Order struct {
        ID int32,
        GID int32,
        CID int32,
        Type string,
        Amount float64
    }
    
    // here msg is [0,"on",[6,1,5,"market",45.7]]
    
    switch msg[1] {
    case "on":
        if rawOrder, ok := msg[2].([]interface{}); ok {
            order := Order{int32(rawOrder[0]), int32(rawOrder[1]), int32(rawOrder[2]), string(rawOrder[3]), float64(rawOrder[4])}
        }
}
```

But I'm getting an error "Cannot convert an expression of the type 'interface{}' to the type 'int32'" and the next step is use switch for every rawOrder[i] type, but it's toooo long.
How can I do it easilly?

Comment: Find the concrete type of rawOrder[0], use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get a value of that type and [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to in32.  For example, fi the concrete type is float64, use `int32(rawOrder[0].(float64))`.  If you are decoding from JSON, then you should show that code.  There are often ways to eliminate type assertions and conversions using features of the JSON decoder.

Comment: I've updated code to show how I read a message. Does it possible to decode msg to struct?

Comment: You have othe problems before you get to decoding the  message.  1. Consider following the advice in the websocket package documentation overview. 2.The call to websocket.Message.Receive fails because the second argument is not a pointer to a string or a pointer to a slice of bytes.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Okey, I can create msg as: var msg string, and after websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &msg), I'll get that msg is '''[0,"on",[6,1,5,"market",45.7]]'''. But how to parse this string to struct? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the codec used on the websocket will always be json, you can formally define `Order` and give it an `UnmarshalJSON` function to do the decoding for you.

```golang
import "golang.org/x/net/websocket"

type Order struct {
    ID, GID, CID int32
    Type         string
    Amount       float64
}

func (o *Order) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var first []json.RawMessage
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &first)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid order, must be array: %w", err)
    }
    if len(first) != 3 {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid order, length must be 3, got %d", len(first))
    }

    var second string
    err = json.Unmarshal(first[1], &second)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid order, second element must be string: %w", err)
    }

    switch second {
    case "on":
        var third []json.RawMessage
        err = json.Unmarshal(first[2], &third)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("invalid order, third element must be array: %w", err)
        }

        if len(third) != 5 {
            return fmt.Errorf("invalid order, element 3 length must be 5, got %d", len(third))
        }

        for i, f := range []interface{}{&o.ID, &o.GID, &o.CID, &o.Type, &o.Amount} {
            err = json.Unmarshal(third[i], f)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("invalid order, wrong type for element 3[%d]: %w", i, err)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    return fmt.Errorf("invalid order, unknown type %q", second)
}

...
var msg *Order
// Server send response: `[0,"on",[6,1,5,"market",45.7]]`
if err := websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &msg); err != nil {
    logger.Println(err)
}

// msg is now an &Order{ID:6, GID:1, CID:5, Type:"market", Amount:45.7}

}
```

The reason the `UnmarshalJSON` function is huge is because your API is bad. If you control the Server; then you should avoid using mixed types in the same array, and you should avoid using arrays for relational data.

Comment: The code in this answer always errors out because the argument to `websocket.Message.Receive` is invalid.  Fix by replacing `websocket.Message.Receive` with `websocket.JSON.Receive`.